# Images not loading on Android 5

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, google-chrome

I'm dealing with an annoying problem: I'm writing a web site and noticed that with Chrome for Android 5 HTML tags 
     
Sometimes you do not see, the browser gives loading error.
I added to the name of the string:
    ? Timestamp = 987459684798
so here's an example:
    
but it did not work.

The same problem I encountered on a iphone.
while on the desktop and on chrome on Android 4.4 works well.
The tests I did do is to check the internet.
the result is:
on wifi + nav secret you see
all other combinations (4g, wifi clear nav) do not work.

Hereafter an example:

```
<img height="24px" id="logo_img" src="img/icons/MH_logo.png?timestamp=1463126761936" alt="">  

<img height="32px" id="avatar_default" class="avatar-default " style="display: block;" src="img/avatar-default.png?timestamp=1463126761936" alt="" href="">
```

the two images "logo_img" and "avatar_default" and are not shown on mobile, but ok on Desktop, and ok if they use wifi + secret navigation.

The wrong result is:[image: images not shown on Android 5 but ok on desktop]

some idea?
thank you

Comment: a bit of code would help!

Comment: put it in your question and format it properly! Do not add code as a comment

Comment: Ok, I've updated the post! thanks

Comment: ' try getting the image to a js variable and them assigning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the image compressor used by UK mobile provider.
Thus, changing all the web sites from http to https solved the problem.
thx